# Spring controller testing with dependencies failing

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-test-mvc

I have the following controller class:

```
@Controller
public class HelloController {

    private final HelloService service;

    public HelloController(HelloService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    public @ResponseBody String greeting() {
        return service.greet();
    }

}
```

As you can see, it accepts a dependency. This all runs fine in the server. However, when testing, it fails:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(HelloController.class)
public class WebLayerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    public void shouldReturnDefaultMessage() throws Exception {
    this.mockMvc.perform(get("/hello")).andDo(print()).andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().string(containsString("Hello World")));
    }
}
```

Below is the output of the log file in target/surefire-reports/

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test set: biz.martyn.footy.WebLayerTest
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 2.278 s <<< FAILURE! - in biz.martyn.footy.WebLayerTest
shouldReturnDefaultMessage(biz.martyn.footy.WebLayerTest)  Time elapsed: 0.005 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'helloController' defined in file [/home/martyn/eclipse-workspace/Footy/target/classes/biz/martyn/footy/controller/HelloController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'biz.martyn.footy.service.HelloService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'biz.martyn.footy.service.HelloService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
```

I understand that `@MockBean` allows me to create a mock of the dependency, but in cases where I don't care to mock it? Here, I'm happy here for the real dependency instance to be used as normal. Or, is it because I'm only testing the web layer that it doesn't instantiate the controller as it would when running the full app?

UPDATE

I also tried `@Autowired` injection rather than constructor. My app works, so the dependency is brought into the controller, but the test fails. Below is the updated controller:

```
@Controller
public class HelloController {

    @Autowired
    private HelloService service;

    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    public @ResponseBody String greeting() {
        return service.greet();
    }

}
```

Comment: I am assuming there is a Spring context somewhere for the application that wires HellowService into the HelloController. How is the Spring context loaded in test execution?

Comment: Wouldn't that be `MockMvc`?

Comment: Maybe, if you had @Autowired the service to the controller, by adding that annotation to either the constructor or the property?  I don't think SPring will autowire things for you without an explicit declaration, either in the code via an annotation, or via an XML context configuration file...

Comment: `@Autowired` seems a more elegant way to do it (see updated post) but the test still fails, even though the app works fine.

Comment: Agree with @moilejter  Spring must be told what to wire together, either through an xml context configuration or annotations. My suspicion is that the test is missing at least some part of the Spring context.

Comment: I'm going by this tutorial if it helps, I can't see anything that I've missed out - https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/ Or, do all @Service annotated dependencies have to be mocked in Spring tests? I don't get any errors if I use `@MockBean` mind you, but it seems I then need to mock the method returns value of greet() too even though I don't care to mock this dependency.

Comment: No, Spring doesn't need any Autowired annotation if you only have one constructor. It autowires dependencies in that constructor by default. So your code is totally fine. If you want to test the whole thing, and not just the web layer with a mocked service layer, then don't use WebMvcTest. Use this: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-testing-with-mock-environment

Comment: @JBNizet You're right :-) - looks like a feature that was added to Spring in 4.3: https://www.baeldung.com/constructor-injection-in-spring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@WebMvcTest` will disable full auto-configuration and instead apply only configuration relevant to MVC tests (i.e. `@Controller`, `@ControllerAdvice`, `@JsonComponent`, Converter/GenericConverter, Filter, WebMvcConfigurer and HandlerMethodArgumentResolver beans but not `@Component`, `@Service` or `@Repository` beans, so you have to use `@MockBean` to satisfy the dependency.